# Interference sound after switching to speaker in pjsip

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, pjsip, avaudiosession, callkit

I use pjsip library and try to turn on speaker. After this during 10 seconds users could hear interference sound. Is it way to fix it?

I am using next code:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil];
```

Also I try to change category with option `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker` without success.

This is happened only during call, for example, I couldn't reproduce this problem for static video (with AVPlayer).

Comment: Any solution for this ?